# Why is this object disappearing in texture paint mode, but is there in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, texture-painting, weight-paint-mode

Link to video https://imgur.com/a/41qLROy

I've tried hitting Alt H, I've tried opening in version 3.6 instead, but no matter what i do this happens. When I switch to textured or weighted paint modes the select

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have toggled X-Ray by mistake. Try to toggle it off and see if that fixes the issue.

[image: X-Ray]

---

This could be an issue with the Viewport Shading Settings. Try to press the button marked in the screenshot below, and tweak the settings.

[image: Viewport Shading Settings]

---

After examining the model, it turned out that the model has most but not all of its geometry hidden in Edit Mode. In modes that display only faces including Texture Paint, nothing shows up. However, in Edit Mode, the remaining geometry gives the impression that the geometry is not hidden.

The fix is simply to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> while in Edit Mode. If you switch to Texture Paint afterwards, you will see all the faces again. I attached screenshots below that show the steps.

This is how the model looks like now in Texture Paint.
[image: Texture Paint Before]

This is how it looks like in Edit Mode.
[image: Edit Mode Before]

This is how it will look like in Edit Mode after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.
[image: Edit Mode After]

This is how it will look like in Texture Paint.
[image: Texture Paint After]

Comment: Still not showing up. Thanks for your reply! here's what happens now, it looks like the mesh is still there in wireframe so I'm very confused https://imgur.com/a/JoMUi3y

Comment: @ZachSheram I attached another screenshot to my answer. Can you share the settings you get by clicking that button.

Comment: thank you for your kindness and help, do you see the issue here? https://imgur.com/a/uKt19qC

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issues there too. This could be a bug with the new Blender version. If it's okay to share the file, I will be able to dig a bit deeper to try to figure out the issue.

Comment: Yeah i thought it might be a 4.0 bug, but the same issue persists in 3.6. not sure how to link the file here, but I posted it on this forum https://blenderartists.org/t/object-disappearing-in-texture-paint-mode-there-in-edit-mode/1493790/3

Comment: I updated my answer with the actual fix. I know you said you tried it, so I attached some screenshots to help you do it correctly.

Comment: Great thank you so much this helps immensely. Seriously appreciate you taking time to assist a rookie.

Comment: You're welcome!